# C++Builder adding event handlers

Tags: events, c++builder

I have a number of controls grouped in containers, say a `TPanel`, with several containers on a `TForm`. The controls have event handlers that I need, like `OnKeyDown`, `OnChange`, etc. But when they fire, the event is sent to the parent form. I need the events to fire in the container, because the response will be dependent on each group's properties. I haven't found a container in C++Builder that can do this, other than a `TForm` or maybe a `TFrame` (which I don't know how to use).

Can I steer the events back to the originating container?

Is there a way to add event handlers to a `TPanel`, or other containers?

Can I group `TForm`s on a `TForm`?

Comment: How are you assigning the event handlers to begin with? At design-time, or in your code? The nice thing about VCL/FMX-style event handlers is that they don't care what classes they are assigned to. You don't HAVE to use `TForm` class methods as event handlers, but event handlers created at design-time will always use the owning `TForm`/`TFrame` for event handlers. In this situation, I would definitely suggest you [learn how to use `TFrame`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Working_with_Frames).

Comment: In any case, most event handlers give you a `Sender` parameter, which points at the component object that is firing the event.  You can cast that component to `TControl` and use its `Parent` property to know which container the component is on.

Comment: Thanks Remy; I learned a bit about TFrames, and they will do what I need. Events still fire in the enclosing TFrom, but at least it is clear what Frame they came from, as in: 

void __fastcall TForm22::TimeFrame1Edit2Change(TObject *Sender)